# How to prove tensor product of orthogonal projections is still orthogonal ？

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, tensor-products

Given $n$ finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, $H_1,\cdots, H_n$, and $n$ orthogonal projections $\mathcal{P_1},\cdots,\mathcal{P_n}$, For $i\in \{1，\cdots, n \}$, $\mathcal{P_i}$ is an orthogonal projection from $H_i$ to one subspace of itself.

Then, how to prove $\mathcal{P_1}\otimes\mathcal{P_2}\otimes,\cdots,\otimes\mathcal{P_n}$ is an orthogonal projection from $H_1\otimes H_2\otimes,\cdots,\otimes H_n$ to the corresponding subspace.

Thank you!

Comment: An operator $P$ is an orthogonal projection if and only if $P^2=P$ and $P^*=P$...